Sqlite fetching speed problem - how to understand explain and compare two queries
I need to join two tables product_features and feature_text to get this output

From a previous question i got two answers that both return the expected result for a small sample set: join so that

each feature of a product is joined with a text
each combination of product + feature + year + text only occurs once
if the text for a given feature (display  DSP) is specific (display 1", display 1.5") for a product_group (B1, UT) than this text should be joined otherwise the general text that is available for this feature (DSP: display).

It seems that something messes up the results because the fetching time is so different. The 50k run

for SELECT f.*, did return 24,587 rows retrieved starting from 1 in 2 m 57 s 653 ms (execution: 3 ms, fetching: 2 m 57 s 650 ms) why did it not return more results?
for Select pf.year  did return 50,000 rows retrieved starting from 1 in 858 ms (execution: 105 ms, fetching: 753 ms)




Author
Query
1K rows
10k rows
50k rows




cafce25
Select f.* ,...
7107 ms
75280 ms
177650 ms*


AlexU
Select pf.year, ...
215 ms
320 ms
932 ms



That Select f.*  did return only 24,587 rows is unexpected. Does one query return more rows than desired or is the other one filtering out rows that are needed?
Question
I would like to understand the different query plans and how to measure the execution speed and also the "math" reason why one query is faster then the other.
Also what am i doing wrong?
SQL
Tables and some sample records
Tables with some sample records
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS product_features;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS feature_text;
CREATE TABLE product_features (
    year INTEGER, -- (4) 
    product TEXT, -- (6) 
    feature TEXT -- (3)      
);
CREATE TABLE feature_text (
    year INTEGER, -- (4)    
    product_group TEXT, 
     -- (2) usually matches the first two digits of product 
     -- but is sometimes empty / NULL or blank ' ' 
    feature TEXT, -- (3)
    language INTEGER, -- (2) 
    description1 TEXT -- up to 40
);

INSERT INTO product_features (year, product, feature) VALUES 
    (2024, 'B12XBE', 'A1C'), (2024, 'B12XBE', '7B0'),
    (2024, 'B12XBE', 'DUL'), (2024, 'UTB2EF', 'A1C'),
    (2024, 'B12XBE', 'DSP'), (2024, 'UTB2EF', 'DSP'),    
    (2024, 'UTB2EF', '7B0'), (2024, 'UTB2EF', 'DUL'),
    (2024, 'X9Y8Z7', 'DUH'), (2024, 'X9Y8Z7', '7B0'),
    (2024, 'X9Y8Z7', 'DSP');

INSERT INTO feature_text
 (year, product_group, feature, language, description1) 
VALUES 
  (2024, 'B1', 'A1C', 1, 'B1 hardened steel'),
  (2024, 'B1', '7B0', 1, 'B1 diamond tip'),
  (2024, 'B1', 'DSP', 1, 'display 1 inch'),
  (2024, 'B1', 'DSP', 2, 'Anzeige 1,5 cm'),  
  (2024, 'UT', 'A1C', 1, 'UT hardened steel'),
  (2024, 'UT', '7B0', 1, 'UT diamond tip'),
  (2024, 'UT', 'DSP', 1, 'display 1,5 inch'),
  (2024, 'UT', 'DSP', 2, 'Anzeige 2,25 cm'),
  (2024, ' ', 'DUL', 1, '10mm for light duty'),
  (2024, 'X9', '7B0', 1, 'X9 diamond tip'),
  (2024, ' ', 'DUH', 1, '13mm for heavy duty'),
  (2024, 'B1', 'A1C', 2, 'B1 gehärteter Stahl'),
  (2024, 'B1', '7B0', 2, 'B1 Diamant Spitze'),
  (2024, 'UT', 'A1C', 2, 'UT gehärteter Stahl'),
  (2024, 'UT', '7B0', 2, 'UT Diamant Spitze'),
  (2024, ' ', 'DUL', 2, '10mm für leichte Aufgaben'),
  (2024, 'X9', '7B0', 2, 'X9 Diamant Spitze'),
  (2024, ' ', 'DUH', 2, '13mm für schwere Aufgaben'),
  (2024, NULL, 'DSP', 1, 'display'),
  (2024, NULL, 'DSP', 2, 'Anzeige');


Two queries to get the result
These are the two queries to get the desired result.
Option 1:  User AlexU
-- User AlexU
SELECT product_features.year,
    product_features.product,
    product_features.feature,
    substr(product_features.product, 1, 2) AS product_group,
    text_en.description1 AS en,
    text_de.description1 AS de
FROM product_features
LEFT JOIN feature_text AS text_en
     ON text_en.year = product_features.year
     AND text_en.feature = product_features.feature
     AND (substr(product_features.product, 1, 2) = text_en.product_group 
          OR text_en.product_group IS NULL 
          OR TRIM(text_en.product_group) = '')
     AND text_en.language = 1
LEFT JOIN feature_text AS text_de
     ON text_de.year = product_features.year
     AND text_de.feature = product_features.feature
     AND (substr(product_features.product, 1, 2) = text_de.product_group 
          OR text_de.product_group IS NULL 
          OR TRIM(text_de.product_group) = '')
     AND text_de.language = 2;

The start of the explain result

Option 2: User cafce25
-- User cafce25
SELECT f.*, substring(f.product, 0, 3) as product_group,
(
  select description1
  from feature_text t
  where f.year = t.year
    and (substring(f.product, 0, 3) = t.product_group 
             or t.product_group = ' ' 
             or t.product_group is null)
    and f.feature = t.feature 
    and language = 1
) as feature_text_en,
(
  select description1
  from feature_text t
  where f.year = t.year
    and (substr(f.product, 0, 3) = t.product_group 
         or t.product_group = ' ' 
         or t.product_group is null)
    and f.feature = t.feature 
    and language = 2
) as feature_text_de
from product_features f;

First rows of 76

SQL to create thousand of dummy records
This sql creates lots of dummy records - add more by changing x < 15000 to a higher number.
-- Clean old records
DELETE FROM feature_text WHERE ROWID > 20;
DELETE FROM product_features WHERE ROWID > 11;

-- Create the products table if it doesn't already exist
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS products (
    product_code TEXT PRIMARY KEY  -- Unique product identifier
);

-- Example insertions into products table as a basis to generate dummy rows
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO products (product_code) VALUES
        ('KBA123'), 
        ('KBB123'), 
        ('BMA123'), 
        ('BMB123'), 
        ('FXA678'), 
        ('FXB789'); 

-- Create the feature_text table if it doesn't already exist
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS feature_text (
        year INTEGER,           -- Year (4 digits)
        product_group TEXT,     -- Product group (fixed value or NULL)
        feature TEXT,           -- Feature description or code (3 characters, alphanumeric)
        language INTEGER,       -- Language (1 for English, 2 for German)
        description1 TEXT       -- Description (up to 40 characters)
);

-- Create the product_features table if it doesn't already exist
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS product_features (
        year INTEGER,   -- Year (4 digits)
        product TEXT,   -- Product value
        feature TEXT    -- Feature description or code (3 characters)
);

-- Use CTE to generate features and insert into feature_text
WITH RECURSIVE
    cnt(x) AS (
        SELECT 1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT x + 1 FROM cnt WHERE x < 15000
    ),
    features AS (
        SELECT
            2024 AS year,          -- Fixed year value
            NULL AS product_group, -- NULL or Hardcoded product group like 'PG'
            substr('ABCDEF1234567890', (x - 1) % 16 + 1, 1) ||
            substr('ABCDEF1234567890', ((x - 1) / 16) % 16 + 1, 1) ||
            substr('ABCDEF1234567890', ((x - 1) / 256) % 16 + 1, 1) AS feature -- Alphanumeric 3-char code
        FROM cnt
    )

INSERT INTO feature_text (year, product_group, feature, language, description1)
SELECT
    year,
    product_group,
    feature,
    language,
    CASE
        WHEN language = 1 THEN 'English description for ' || feature
        WHEN language = 2 THEN 'German description for ' || feature
        END AS description1
FROM features,
     (SELECT 1 AS language UNION ALL SELECT 2) languages;


-- Insert features into product_features using the products table
INSERT INTO product_features (year, product, feature)
SELECT
    f.year,
    p.product_code AS product,
    f.feature
FROM feature_text f
         JOIN products p
              ON f.product_group IS NULL  -- Ensure only features with NULL product_group are used
WHERE f.feature IS NOT NULL    -- Ensure feature is not NULL
  AND f.ROWID > 20               -- Adjust this condition based on your needs
GROUP BY f.year, p.product_code, f.feature;

Explain Sample



I would like to understand the different query plans and how to measure the execution speed and also the "math" reason why one query is faster then the other. Also what am i doing wrong?

I am not sure what tool do you use to look at the query plan, but the table you showed is not a good way to look at it. sqlite can show the plan in two ways:

EXPLAIN <select ...> produces a set of steps the engine will do to resolve the query (that is what you see).
EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN <select ...> produces a human readable text describing which indexes would be used, or which table would be joined to which. (that is what you probably looking for).

Try researching your tool for a better view of plans, or just switch to a different tool. For example, the console sqlite3 tool shows these query plans:
-- first query
|--SCAN product_features
|--SEARCH text_en USING AUTOMATIC COVERING INDEX (year=? AND feature=? AND language=?)
`--SEARCH text_de USING AUTOMATIC COVERING INDEX (year=? AND feature=? AND language=?)

-- second query
|--SCAN f
|--CORRELATED SCALAR SUBQUERY 1
|  `--SCAN t
`--CORRELATED SCALAR SUBQUERY 2
   `--SCAN t

These query plans explain why one query is much faster - it scans one table and does a search in two others. While the second query scans one table and for each row in it scans two other tables.

The difference in number of rows is because both queries are semi-incorrect. They do rely on ideal input data and therefore they are doing different things.

Query with a joins does believe in uniqueness of rows in feature_text by combination of fields (year, feature, product_group, language). But what if you have two rows in feature_text with same combination of these fields? In this case, the left join will put both of them against one row from product_features. 
As result, query from AlexU gives you much more rows than you have in product_features
Query with subselect also has the very same assumption on uniqueness of  (year, feature, product_group, language). But since the main part of the query based solely on product_features, you are getting in the final recordset same rows as in product_features. But if you have multiple rows in feature_text, the sqlite shows you just one of them. That is actually wont work in any other RDBMS - as soon as subselect attempt to present two rows - the error will happen in MySQL, Oracle, SQL Server... and all other RDBMS. That is a dubious feature of sqlite to forgive this error.

You can avoid that issue with adding unique (year, feature, product_group, language) into definition of feature_text. Which will prevent you from having "bad data" in the table, and both queries will return same recordsets.
Or you can modify both queries to force them return just one row with such group. As a variant, you can do
-- User AlexU
SELECT product_features.year,
    product_features.product,
    product_features.feature,
    substr(product_features.product, 1, 2) AS product_group,
    min(text_en.description1) AS en,
    min(text_de.description1) AS de
FROM product_features
LEFT JOIN feature_text AS text_en
     ON text_en.year = product_features.year
     AND text_en.feature = product_features.feature
     AND (substr(product_features.product, 1, 2) = text_en.product_group 
          OR text_en.product_group IS NULL 
          OR TRIM(text_en.product_group) = '')
     AND text_en.language = 1
LEFT JOIN feature_text AS text_de
     ON text_de.year = product_features.year
     AND text_de.feature = product_features.feature
     AND (substr(product_features.product, 1, 2) = text_de.product_group 
          OR text_de.product_group IS NULL 
          OR TRIM(text_de.product_group) = '')
     AND text_de.language = 2
GROUP BY  product_features.year,
    product_features.product,
    product_features.feature,
    substr(product_features.product, 1, 2) AS product_group

-- User cafce25
SELECT f.*, substring(f.product, 0, 3) as product_group,
(
  select min(description1)
  from feature_text t
  where f.year = t.year
    and (substring(f.product, 0, 3) = t.product_group 
             or t.product_group = ' ' 
             or t.product_group is null)
    and f.feature = t.feature 
    and language = 1
) as feature_text_en,
(
  select min(description1)
  from feature_text t
  where f.year = t.year
    and (substr(f.product, 0, 3) = t.product_group 
         or t.product_group = ' ' 
         or t.product_group is null)
    and f.feature = t.feature 
    and language = 2
) as feature_text_de
from product_features f;

Of course, this will add additional run time to the queries, so clean-data way is preferable. But that is for you to decide.

The tool used for the EXPLAIN image is GoLand but it only displays the result of sqlite> EXPLAIN SELECT .... I just noticed that indentations are missing compared to sqlite.exe explain example - indentation from addr 4 to 12.

I wonder if there is a way to do a simple left join first to get all product_features joined with matching text SELECT * from pf LEFT JOIN t on pf.feature = t.feature AND pf.year = t.year and substr(pf.product,1,2) = t.product_group and then get only the rows that have no text as input and join them against text with this condition year=year and feature=feature and union them?
